# Name of an anime show

Tags: inuyasha

I am trying to recall a show from my childhood.

I've watched it sometime before 2000/2001, but it could have been from many years before that.

I really don't remember the story, but

- It was about a school girl (which anime isn't ;) )
- She traveled to some kind of fantasy world (I don't remember if she traveled back and forth, or if the school-time was flashbacks)
- There was a water well that had something to do with this traveling
- She had skills in shooting arrows
- The title screen or the commercials screen had two dice on it - I clearly remember the dice
- I think the title was like "foul-play" or "role-play" (again the association with dice) or something, but I am very vague on it.

Comment: Do you remember anything about the story? i.e. How did the girl survive/live in the fantasy world?

Comment: Not really. It was more about relationships and romance than anything else.

Comment: Pretty odd remembering Inuyasha anime without remembering himself.

Comment: @Lohoris I know, I was thinking the same. Once I saw the screenshot, the memories immediately returned, including Inuyasha. But before that, I remembered only what I posted in the OP. I just remembered that there was an anime show that I watched as a kid and liked it for all the "character development/relationships", something that was not present in mainstream western cartoons at the time (like G.I.Joe)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[image]

This sounds like [Inuyasha](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inuyasha), based on a manga by Rumiko Takahashi. The girl in question is "[Kagome Higurashi](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Inuyasha_characters#Kagome_Higurashi)" and her male counterpart is a half-demon named Inuyasha. She also shoots arrows that are tipped with a special jewel shard. She travels back and forth from the fantasy world through a well in the back of her temple.

[image]

[image]

More info:

- [Wikia](http://inuyasha.wikia.com/wiki/Inuyasha)
- [Anime News Network](http://www.animenewsnetwork.com/encyclopedia/manga.php?id=76)
- [My Anime List](http://myanimelist.net/character/1353/Inuyasha)

Comment: OMG yes that's it!

Comment: I guess the "dice" are those octagonal shapes. And somehow "(Fairy) Tail" sounds like "(Foul) Play" to me.

Comment: @Slav Yeah, I wasn't sure about the dice part or the opening. The show is really long and has like 6 or 7 openings (or maybe more). I haven't seen all of it so I couldn't tell.